# Restore VLC 1.x functionality after installing VLC 2.x

Tags: 11.10, vlc

For several users, installing VLC 2.0 from it's PPA will result in multiple problems with the system, including but not limited to:

- Openshot not working
- DeVeDe not working
- Pitivi not working
- Sound problems
- Similar video tools having problems

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to go back to 1.x since several libraries/tools are shared between other programs that VLC uses.

To solve this first:

1. Remove the PPA from VLC 2.X from your **Software Sources**
2. Run this in the terminal so it removes any trace of VLC 2.X:

   `sudo apt-get purge vlc libvlc5 libvlccore5 vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse`
3. Update Repositories: `sudo apt-get update`
4. Install VLC 1.x: `sudo apt-get install vlc`

I'm sorry that I had to Ask and Answer this but do to some help about this with several friends and users here I thought it would be better to put it right now than wait. Hope it helps anybody that updates to VLC 2.x and finds problems after.